# MySQLdb delete query - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to run a delete query using MySQLdb and passing 3 variables. The query is run as follows:

```
self.cursor.execute("""DELETE er.* FROM extension_recording er, 
  extension e, client c 
 WHERE er.extension_id = e.id AND e.client_id = c.id 
  AND c.parent_client_id = %s 
  AND DATE(er.cr_date) BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'""" , 
(client_id, start_date, end_date))
```

Please excuse the indenting, couldn't seem to make it legible without.

And what happens is this: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

I've tried passing the SQL to the cursor as a string (I know this is vulnerable to SQL injection, was just testing) and the result is the same. I've examined the SQL and it seems fine.

Is this something to do with the single quoted dates in the query? Or something else?

Comment: Does it work if you change `BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'` to `BETWEEN %s AND %s`? If not, what are the types of `client_id`, `start_date`, and `end_date`?

Comment: No that doesn't work, tried that already. Client ID is a string, the other two are dates.

Comment: I guess maybe a better question would be, how should I run the delete query using MySQLdb, given that I need to use dates as criteria? Is this the best way or is there some other method?

Comment: I just tried a similar example, and I can't reproduce the fault. You say you tried passing the SQL as a string, by which I assume you mean you interpolated the values before executing the query. Can you include the exact SQL you get when you do this? TBH, though, I don't see anything wrong with that code, so are you certain that's the query which is producing the error? Might help to include the full stack traceback.

Comment: @Aya Thanks for the continued help, here's the SQL before execution: `DELETE er.* FROM extension_recording er, extension e, client c 
WHERE er.extension_id = e.id AND e.client_id = c.id AND c.parent_client_id = 0009 
AND DATE(er.cr_date) BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-15' `

Comment: @Aya and here is the traceback in full: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/recording_archive_newer.py", line 194, in <module>
    print "Error %s deleting from DB" % (sys.exc_info())
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: Also I've confirmed that there are some records to delete, not that I would have thought this would cause an error

Answer (score 1):

There's a clue in the traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/recording_archive_newer.py", line 194, in <module>
    print "Error %s deleting from DB" % (sys.exc_info())
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The problem is not with the query, but with printing the error message.

[`sys.exc_info()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) returns a tuple of three elements, but you've only specified one placeholder in the string `"Error %s deleting from DB"`.

It's worth noting that `(sys.exc_info())` is not a tuple with one element, but is interpreted as `sys.exc_info()`. If you want to make it a one-element tuple, you need a trailing comma, i.e. `(sys.exc_info(),)`.

However, if that line is part of a block like...

```
try:
    # do query
except:
    print "Error %s deleting from DB" % (sys.exc_info())
```

...you'd be better off re-raising the original exception, otherwise it'll be really difficult to work out where the actual problem is. I'd suggest changing it to something like...

```
try:
    # do query
except:
    print "Error deleting from DB"
    raise
```

...at least while you're debugging.